# Incompatible OpenSearch 1.3 connector for Spark 3.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-spark

We used to have Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11 and Elastic Search 6.8 in our servers.

Our servers were recently upgraded and Spark was upgraded to **3.1.2** and Scala to **2.12**. We were getting the below error when writing records to Elastic Search. So we upgraded from ES 6.8 to 7.10 but we found that ES connectors are only available for 7.12 or higher versions to connect to Spark 3.x.

So I upgraded to **OpenSearch 1.3.10** since AWS was migrated to OpenSearch from Elastic Search after 7.10. Even after that I'm getting the same error. The elastic search jar I'm using right know is **elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-7.13.2.jar**.

We cannot downgrade the Spark version (as servers are not in our control) we need a solution to write data to OpenSearch 1.3.

code:

```
esconf={}
esconf["es.mapping.id"] = var_document_id
esconf["es.nodes"] = var_elasticsearch_host
esconf["es.port"] = var_elasticsearch_port
esconf["es.nodes.wan.only"]= "true"
dataframe.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").options(**esconf).mode("append").save(var_elasticsearch_index+'/'+var_document_type)
```

Error:

```
 Full Error Code is :{error_code: <class py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError>, error_message: An error occurred while calling o123.save.\n: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class\n\tat org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:220)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:105)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:194)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:232)\n\tat org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:229)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:190)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:133)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class\n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)\n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)\n\t... 40 more\n, error_at: EXCEPTION IN (/mnt/efs/home/svc-1019183/STORKAPP_DEV/app/utils/utility.py,LINE 2502 dataframe.write.format(org.elasticsearch.spark.sql).options(**esconf).mode(append).save(var_elasticsearch_index+\/\+var_document_type))}
2022-11-14 09:08:11,151 
Error Message is :An error occurred while calling o123.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:220)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 40 more
```

I ran the below satatement in the OpenSearch dev Tools as well

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
"persistent" : {
"compatibility.override_main_response_version" : true
}
}
```

Response of `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults=true`

```
...
    "compatibility" : {
      "override_main_response_version" : "true"
    }
  },
...
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the opensearch-hadoop connector? It was written to address connectivity to OpenSearch from Spark.

https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-hadoop